# Xamarin.Android AndroidEnvironment file not applied to change GC Bridge implementation

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I've added a file called `env.conf` with the following content

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=tarjan
MONO_GC_PARAMS=nursery-size=128m
MONO_GC_PARAMS=soft-heap-limit=512m
```

to my Android project and configured its build action as `AndroidEnvironment`. Unfortunately, the output of the application states that the old bridge implementation is used for garbage collection:

> 07-09 09:43:34.042 D/Mono    (32084): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 228 num_hash_entries 2049 sccs size 1277 init 0.00ms df1 7.35ms sort 2.87ms dfs2 2.96ms setup-cb 0.40ms free-data 3.11ms links 2593/2593/1284/16 dfs passes 4870/3870
>
> 07-09 09:43:34.042 D/Mono    (32084): GC_MAJOR: (LOS overflow) pause 60.33ms, total 61.31ms, bridge 45.65ms major 6864K/6608K los 510K/12016K

I'm using Xamarin 3.11.666.0 and Xamarin.Android 5.1.4.16, which seems to be the latest versions of those packages as of now.

How can I apply a new bridge implementation for the app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combine them onto a single line:

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=tarjan,nursery-size=128m,soft-heap-limit=512m
```

For some reason none of the parameters are applied when you declare it line-by-line.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you assign those values to the **same** variable, thus only the last one will have effect.

You can do it line by line this way:

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=tarjan
MONO_GC_PARAMS=$MONO_GC_PARAMS,nursery-size=128m
MONO_GC_PARAMS=$MONO_GC_PARAMS,soft-heap-limit=512m
```